# Spritefont Files not Drawing Monogame

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, monogame, spritefont

I am working with Xamarin on Mac and my spritefonts are not drawing on IOS.
they seem to not be appearing at all, despite all the files being loaded into ContentManager. does anyone know what a solution to this is?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the issues with SpriteFont's. They seem to be fairly common. My workaround is to use the BMFont tool instead. http://dylanwilson.net/bmfont-rendering-with-monogame-extended